# c system function gets before other strings

Tags: c, system

i am trying to write a simple c program that prints the C compiler version. so i wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("you have %d", system("gcc --version");
}
```

the output:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

you have compiler 0
```

any idea?

Comment: what is yor question?

Comment: Did you read the [`system` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)? What does it tell you is the return value for `system`?

Comment: You might want to post the actual code that produces the output, not something vaguely similar. Also, read the manpage for `system()`.

Comment: how can i write it so it will be in the right order? i mean that it will print something like:

you have compiler you have gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: For starters, don't use `system` as it doesn't do what you seem to want it to. Try [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead. Or you can run `system` *after* the `printf`. And edit your question with your above comment as it explains what you are really asking about.

Answer (score 1):

`system` executes a shell command and returns the status of the command. A value of 0, as in your case, means the command was run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `printf` is printing the return value of the `system` call. The return value of the system call, according to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), is the return status of the command being called (`gcc` in this case).

Since the call to gcc is successful, the return value is '0'. This, then, is the value printed by your program:

```
you have compiler 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    unsigned major, minor, build;
    system("gcc --version > gccoutput.txt");

    fp = fopen("gccoutput.txt", "r");
    if (fp) {
        fscanf(fp, "gcc (GCC) %u.%u.%u", &major, &minor, &build);
        printf("Major: %u, minor: %u, build: %u\n", major, minor, build);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

My output was gcc (GCC) 4.6.2 etc

So for your output you will have to change.  Or make it work on any string before x.y.z

A more flexible solution could use:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[A-Za-z() ]%u.%u.%u", s, &major, &minor, &build);
```

s is a char buffer.